# How avoid primitive error in database test with Karate automation and JDBC driver

Tags: database, karate

@Thomas,

How avoid primitive error in database test with Karate automation and JDBC driver.

Because today when I use "variable = field.lengt" for fields as INTEGER type I received the null return and not the correct lenght.
Only to work with caracter column type.

Do you know the reason? Or how Can I compare the lenght value returned by database column with Karate automation?

Comment: sorry karate has nothing to do with JDBC - please read my comments on the linked answer

Comment: Helo @PeterThomas, currently I am using Karate to recover data from database.

No problem about this, my doubt is about:

How Can I compare the lenght column value returned from database with Karate automation? I would like compare numeric and character columns.

Comment: then please read this: https://github.com/intuit/karate#type-conversion